# Can't get access to internal storage from app using file manager

Tags: android

I want my app to be able to pick files and use it.
For this purpose I use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("file/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select file"), SELECT_FILE);
```

But when file manager opens, it starts from sdcard directory. And when I click on Internal storage button nothing happens. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9cFV.png)

How can I make this button work? And what code can I write to make file manager start from Internal storage's directory?

Comment: "How can I make this button work? And what code can I write to make file manager start from Internal storage's directory?" -- ask the developers of that file manager. That is not part of standard Android. BTW, `file/*` is not a valid MIME type.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access app private storage if it is not your app. So if you want to share some privately stored data with other apps, either implement Content Provider in your app or simply copy said file/data to publicly available storage.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have permissions to be able to access private storage.